# TaskQueue : double conditional-sequence execution (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, task-queue, tbb

I'm writing a server application, task oriented. Each Session (client) send packets to the server, the server enqueues them as Tasks, and workers (threads) handle them.
Constraints are :

- Tasks from a same Session have to be **always** sequentially executed ( => if a thread begin to handle a Task of a Session, another thread cannot handle a Task for the same Session while the first is not finished)
- Tasks of some types have to be sequentially executed
- Tasks of some other type don't have to be sequentially executed

**What could be the best approach to do that ? how do we call this concept ?** (I guess it is not *double conditional-sequence execution*)

I ideally would use [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) to achieve that but I don't know if a feature of TBB just fit for my need.
(I'm open for any other propositions)

Here a piece of "pseudo-code" which would be my first idea *[EDIT: but is wrong, sequential execution is not assured, but the code could explain my idea]* :

```cpp
struct Session {
    atomic<bool> locked;
}
struct Task {
    char type;
    Session* session;
    void execute() { ; }
};

atomic<bool> type_locked[SEQ_TYPE_NUMBER];

threadsafe_selfiterable_list<Task> list;

void do() {
    while( alive ) 
    {
        if( list.empty() )
            relax();
        if( list.has_next() ) {
            task = list.next();
            if( !compare_and_swap( task.session->locked, true ) ) {
                if( is_non_sequential_task_type( task.type ) ) {
                    queue.pop();
                    task.execute();
                } else if( !compare_and_swap( type_locked[task.type], true ) ) {
                    queue.pop();
                    task.execute();
                    type_locked[task.type] = false;
                }
                task.session->locked = false;
            }
        } else 
            list.rewind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a 'TaskCollection' Task that can hold, and execute, other tasks. If there are sequential task/s, shove them into a TaskCollection and submit that to your threadpool.

Comment: The problem is the "double" sequential : a same task is sequential by his 'producer', and can be by the type. (note that my pseudo-code is currently wrong)